# “Apple cannot check it for malicious software” in every Installation

Tags: homebrew, macos-catalina, homebrew-cask

I'm always getting the error message “Apple cannot check it for malicious software” when I run a software after installing using `brew install` or `brew cask install`, so my question is, is there a solution to make my Mac trust installations of Homebrew? I know I could use
`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine <folder of app>` but it's kinda annoying doing it all the time....

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Credit to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491 :

> In macOS Catalina and macOS Mojave, when an app fails to install
>   because it hasn’t been notarized or is from an unidentified developer,
>   it will appear in System Preferences > Security & Privacy, under the
>   General tab. Click Open Anyway to confirm your intent to open or
>   install the app.

[image: apple-image]

> The warning prompt reappears, and you can click Open.*

[image: apple-image]

> The app is now saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it in the future by double-clicking it, just as you can any authorized app.
>
> - **If you're prompted to open Finder: control-click the app in Finder, choose Open from the menu, and then click Open in the dialog that appears. Enter your admin name and password to open the app**.